# Is Erza's samurai costume considered an armor?

Tags: fairy-tail

That famous costume where her hair is tied in a very long huge pony tail and she has only bandages on her torso and this baggy red hakama pants with a katana.

Is that an armor? If so, what's the name?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There really is no name for the armor, some people call it the Japanese Cloth armor but the fact is that it is not really armor. It is a completely offensive requip in which she puts all of her power into her sword for attacks. On the wiki page for her battle against *[Azuma](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Azuma)* it states:

> Erza decides that in order to defeat him, she has to collect all of her Magic into a single offensive attack without wasting any on defensive power. She requips into her Japanese-like clothes, previously used in her battle against Ikaruga in, stating that she has no need for armor and only her sword.

On her *[wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Erza_Scarlet)* page you can see that the requip in question is not listed. 
For a complete listing of her armors you can find that here: *[Armors](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Armors)*

Answer (score 1):

It does not have a name, because it is not an armour. It is just fabric after all. As [Ikaruga](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Ikaruga) mentions, there is no magic coming from Erza's outfit.

[image]